# Difference between Alert vs search objects in Splunk?

Tags: rest, splunk

I'm consuming splunk's rest api to access Splunk objects. The goal is to disable/enable saved alerts(not all search objects) based on the title inputted. The approach I have taken is to access

https://{machine}:8089/servicesNS/admin/search/saved/searches/

and compare the titles. But the requirement is to disable the object only if it is an Alert(the ones displayed in this page

http://{machine}:8000/en-US/app/search/alerts

This is just a subset of the results displayed in

http://{machine}:8000/en-US/manager/launcher/saved/searches?ns=-&pwnr=-&search=≈p_only=1

I'm checking to see if property "actions" is not empty or property "alert.track" is "1" to check if it is an alert. But it looks like a new search query with some conditions added is also displayed in the alerts page.

So I would like to know if there is a combination of properties that I can use to distinguish an alert from a search object?

Comment: Not sure how this relates to PowerShell?

Comment: I'm consuming the rest-api through Powershell. Should have mentioned that in the post. Thanks!